# Getting Around Alpha Bug for Preview in Sierra 10.12.2

Tags: macos, preview

I'm running into the problem accurately described here:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4229655?start=0&tstart=0

Summary: I take a JPG image, use a selection tool to remove the background so that it will be transparent, and then save the image as a PNG. The image background is represented as black, instead of transparent.

The link there shows that it's a "color profile" bug - is there a correct color profile that supports transparency?

Comment: Why don't you start with a png, as that already supports transparency? I feel we've only got half of the issue described here, or we have an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)

Comment: Oh should have mentioned - it's a piece of stock art I bought that's only jpg.

Comment: Sorry, I can't repro, no matter what profile I use. If I knock the background out of a jpg, it automatically changes to png24 & then preserves transparency. Might be OS-dependant?

Comment: Can you try using this image? http://www.123rf.com/search.php?word=woman+silhouette&imgtype=&Submit=+&t_word=&t_lang=en&orderby=0&sti=mf8koyinwwjuj71l89|&mediapopup=43253933

Comment: Yeah, that goes black. I'd try Photoshop or Gimp - something a bit more graphics-oriented. As soon as you switch it from being a background layer, photoshop will delete to transparent.

Comment: btw, I don't think it's a "profile bug" I think it's that that specific file's current background is black. changing its layer structure in pshop then allows photoshop to create a new background of 'transparent'. imnsho, I'd say the original image is 'wrong'.

Comment: I'm not an expert here, but when I select everything that's gray in the jpg, then delete it, why doesn't it fill it with "transparency"?

Comment: ...because it fills with whatever is the current background layer, which appears to be black. Unless you can force it to become a separate layer of its own, that cannot be changed. Preview is the most basic of editors, it is simply not designed for such a task, you need a dedicated graphics package.

Comment: Gotcha - can you bubble up and make it an answer and I'll give you the check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though this problem is old, I did figure out a solution that works (on Mojave at least, haven't tried it anywhere else).

1. Find a PNG image somewhere that already has a transparent background.
2. In Preview, remove the contents of that image and resize it to match your source image.
3. Copy the source image and paste it onto this (now blank) PNG image.
4. **Export** the image as PNG, making sure Alpha is checked. You now have an image with transparent background and your old image as a second layer.
5. You can use the Magic Alpha on this new image and it will be saved properly.

Hope this helps anyone out there still struggling with this!

Answer (score 1):

It seems to depend on how the image was made in the first place, & what its current background is set to.

Testing with the [example given in comments](http://www.123rf.com/search.php?word=woman%20silhouette&imgtype=&Submit=%20&t_word=&t_lang=en&orderby=0&sti=mf8koyinwwjuj71l89%7C&mediapopup=43253933) I see the same behaviour as the OP when using Preview.
Even in Photoshop the same thing happens... unless I turn the image into an unlocked layer first. After that, erasing will then erase to transparent.

I've tested with other images made in photoshop with transparency, then saved as jpg. I also checked converting the jpg to png first, before testing.
It seems Preview is not the only app which will knock out to a predetermined colour, Photoshop will do the same, unless first converted to a separate layer. [In Photoshop you get the choice of which colour, but 'transparent' isn't an option.]

I'd say therefore, it's not a bug, it's intended behaviour; a limitation of a single-layered image.

I see no way round this except to use a dedicated graphics package, like Photoshop or Gimp.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a helpful answer posted in the [Apple discussion from the original Q](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4229655?start=0&tstart=0):

1. instead of editing an existing image, take a screenshot of the image – <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>5</kbd> on most Mac's
2. remove the background from the screenshot using Preview's *Instant Alpha* markup tool
3. save the image and the edited screenshot should have a transparent background :)